# Modifying vertex properties while traversing

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I want to modify *some property* for all vertices connected via edges with *some label* in JanusGraph using Gremlin in Java. I tried the following:

```
public void setAllProperties(JanusGraphTransaction janusGraphTransaction) {
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal = janusGraphTransaction.traversal().V();
    traversal.has("SomeLabel", "SomeProperty", 0)
            .repeat(out("SomeEdgeLabel"))
            .property("SomeProperty", true)
            .until(outE("SomeEdgeLabel").count().is(0));
}
```

But no vertices are modified. I tried googling for modifying properties while traversing using *repeat... until* but without any success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you need to `iterate()` your traversal - see [tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration) - thus:

```
public void setAllProperties(JanusGraphTransaction janusGraphTransaction) {
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal = janusGraphTransaction.traversal().V();
    traversal.has("SomeLabel", "SomeProperty", 0)
            .repeat(out("SomeEdgeLabel"))
            .property("SomeProperty", true)
            .until(outE("SomeEdgeLabel").count().is(0)).iterate();
}
```

then, move the `property()` inside the `repeat()`:

```
public void setAllProperties(JanusGraphTransaction janusGraphTransaction) {
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal = janusGraphTransaction.traversal().V();
    traversal.has("SomeLabel", "SomeProperty", 0)
            .repeat(out("SomeEdgeLabel").property("SomeProperty", true))
            .until(outE("SomeEdgeLabel").count().is(0)).iterate();
}
```

`property()` is not a type of `Map` step - it just passes the `Vertex` through so your traversal keeps working.

Comment: It works if I emit vertices then modify them in stream/list but the number of vertices will be extremely large - they won't fit into the memory. That's way I need to edit them while traversing.

Comment: updated answer based on your comment. i think that's what you want anyway. i think you can drop the `until()` in this case as well